# How do you create a settings function in codeigniter?

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I have created a MY_Controller and I'm linking to it through my main controller... I am now trying to create a settings function which will get all the results from a database and return the one you want... The only problem I'm having is being able to do using the template engine...

```
protected function settings()
{
    // select all settings from database
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM settings');

    // get result from database
    $this->data['settings'] = $query->result_array();

    // return array of data
    return $this->data['settings'];
}
```

How can i go about this?

The only way I can access it at the moment is:

```
{settings}
    {name}
    {value}
{/settings}
```

P.S. I call the function `$this->settings()` in the __construct() function also I forgot to mention I'm using codeigniter

Comment: your using a template engine instead of just using view files?  what template engine?

Comment: I'm using the template parser built into codeigniter...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controller code:

```
$data['settings'] = $this->settings();
$this->load->view('whatever_your_view_file_is_named', $data);
```

Now in your view the setting properties will be available as members of an object named settings as that was the key you set in the data array you pass to the view.

View code:

```
echo $settings->name;
```